# use a listview with a sort combobox and a number of items on a page combobox

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, listview, jquery-ui-sortable, pager

Can someone give a hint how to use a listview with a sort combobox and a number of items on a page combobox? I am manually databinding the ListView control on init when there is no postback, and I also databind it when any combobox changes (they have AutoPostBack == true). Seems to work, but when I use the attached pager control, then other pages just don't get selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PreRender event in the DataPage should be binding your data.

```
<asp:DataPager ID="MyDataPager" runat="server" PagedControlID="YourListViewControlName"
PageSize="3" OnPreRender="MyDataPager_PreRender">

protected void DataPagerProducts_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    YourDataList db = new YourDataList();
    this.YourListViewControlName.DataSource = db.GetAll(); // just an example method
    this.YourListViewControlName.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Correct + have to use DataPager.SetPageProperties if number of items per page has changed.